# Building and Installing to ios 3.2

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, xcode3.2

I recently installed the latest version of xcode with support for ios 4. Unfortunately when I tried to compile and install my app (which I have successfully compiled many times) for my iPod touch (first generation) I get the error that the target I have set requires ios 3.2 and above. I have looked around for a 3.2 update but have not been able to come up with anything. iTines claims my iPod is up to date with ios 3.1.3. My question is, does ios 3.2 exist or, how do I target my first gen iPodtouch to work with with the latest version of xcode?

Comment: iOS 3.2 is the version of iOS for iPad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iOS 3.2 is only for the iPad.

Click on your project name and hit get info.  Then select the build tab.  Set the iPhone OS Deployment Target to 3.1.3

Answer (score 0):

No-one else has pointed out that you need to select the 4.0 SDK in addition to setting the deployment target.  It took me a while to grok that.